# How to allow a user to “select all” rows in a PBI table visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I can't just click one row hold shift and click the bottom of the table to select all. I was trying to avoid having folks needing to download a csv of the data and just do the rclick -> Copy -> Selected Values.

But its a hassle if the table is large you'd have to click on each row individually

Comment: I agree. This is a current limitation. Miguel Myers is taking suggestions on LinkedIn to revamp the core visuals and you may want to suggest it to him. https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7056740970050060289/